# Use javascript variable for video source in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a javascript variable as my source video URL in HTML but cant figure it out.  I'm able to collect the URL and store it as a variable using javascript, but dont know where to go from there.  I'm trying to render this video inside a Widget in Jedox.  a Widget in Jedox is typically used to render things via html/css/javascript. The widget UI is shown below.  the Formula under Source is just a named range in the spreadsheet where this widget will be.

[image]

**The code below is what is in the HTML editor for the Widget.**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>

<body>
   
<script type="text/javascript">
    function __exec(params) 
{
    var vCont = document.getElementById('valContainer'),
    vContCnt = '<br>';
    for (var param in params)
    vContCnt = vContCnt.concat(params[param], '<br>');
    vCont.innerHTML = vContCnt;
}
</script>

<div id="valContainer">  
  
<video width="720" height="240" autoplay>
    <source src=??? type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
  
</div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

When i save and let it compile, this is all i see:

[image]

I dont know how to use the javascript variable in the HTML code as my source.

Comment: You can't do that.
You have to get the video in JS and assign the source from there.

Comment: @Xion14 is that something you could help me with?